# Deleted question after it was answered

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

A user asked a question about his code and why it wasn't working. It was a simple and basic Python issue where he forgot to include his closing strings on some of his lines, causing parts of the program to cause issues, throwing errors and the rest of his code wasn't responding. It was easy to pick up and I gave him a detailed answer of the first line that was causing the issue, followed below with the rest of his code that was corrected.

After providing a comprehensive response to the user's question, including information to the issue, he then realized how easy it is to fix the issue. He may have felt embarrassed about asking that question, and deleted his post with no acknowledgement of my answer.

In order to encourage more people to help others, should the user be advised to acknowledge those who provide helpful solutions?

Comment: Doesn't forgetting to close the quotes constitute a typo?

Comment: It was more that I was explaining the error he was facing as what he provided as his error was long and most of it was irrelevant

Comment: Right but you said the issue was closing strings. I assume the quotes weren't balanced. So, isn't that a typo regardless of what the error message is? Or is there no dupe target? It just seems like a question that doesn't have a lot of value for future visitors. From your description it sounds like a minor error. If it's very common then was it really the first question on SO about that? Point being that I'm not sure preserving these questions serves a good purpose.

Comment: Alright thanks that makes sense, I just feel it is the point that trying to extend and making a good explanation of an answer was just for the effort then just to be deleted without any acknowledgement

Comment: that happens with dupes all the time. Stragley sometimes i see high rep users that still give an answer after closing

Comment: It's the weekend - once your answer was copypasta into OP assignment, the evidence of cheating had to be removed.  Such behaviour is common, and the posters don't give a toss about your efforts once they have their answer.

Comment: Giving detailed answers to trivial typo issues is simply polishing a turd. There is no long term value to the SO knowledge base for very localized polished turds that can be answered with a simple comment. Sounds like you are overvaluing your contribution to this turd polishing simply due to the unmerited effort you put in.

Comment: You can, however, ask a better question that isn't caused by a typo or asking to explain why the error message means.

Comment: That's a great illustration of one of the reasons we close typo questions, as I mentioned [here yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405398/what-should-happen-to-questions-about-simple-programming-errors#comment826134_405398). Typos often lead to error messages that are baffling or misleading, especially for new coders. So even if the OP posts all the relevant code, and does their best to describe the problem, it's really unlikely for future readers with the same problem to *find* that question.

Answer (score 7):

If the asker requests you to delete your answer so he can delete his question, you may point him to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) covering some thoughts about the deletion of questions. You can especially cite this paragraph:

> If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if *you* no longer want the answers, somebody else might. This is why the system prevents you from deleting answered questions most of the time.

In your case, I think it's too late to give this advice to the asker if he already deleted his post. Further more, as others pointed out in the comments, if the problem of the asker was really just caused by a typo, it would have been better to just mention the missing quotes in the comments and to vote for closing the question as *Not reproducible or was caused by a typo* afterwards.